# How to build pyodide for iOS 12?

Tags: python, pyodide

Pyodide is working on iOS v13 and v14 but sometimes I get following errors on iOS v13.

[image]

It is out of memory errors. Current pyodide size is approx. 25MB. So, are there any way to get rid of these errors? How can I build for very minimum usage **not** for scientific projects to make it run on iOS v12 also?

Thanks

http://infinyte7.github.io/image-occlusion-in-browser/pwa/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sometimes I get following errors on iOS v13

You should open a Github issue about it. It's likely a bug somewhere. You could try building with `TOTAL_MEMORY` multiplied by 2, to see if it helps.

> How can I build for very minimum usage not for scientific projects to make it run on iOS v12 also?

If you don't load those packages, they have no impact on the main pyodide package, which consists only of CPython + Python/JS type conversion code.

Comment: Issues opened, I will try to build with `TOTAL_MEMORY` multiplied by 2. Thanks